# Fermat's last theorem algorithm in Python

Tags: python, algorithm, python-3.x, math

I have created a program in Python to look for solutions to Fermat's Last Theorem (I know this is not solvable, but I am just using it as a programming exercise). Fermat's Last Theorem states that:

> No three positive integers a, b, and c satisfy the equation a^n + b^n = c^n for any integer value of n greater than 2.

Source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_Last_Theorem)

My algorithm (in Python) is here:

```
from fractions import Fraction

def root(num):
    return num ** Fraction(1 / power)

def two_numbers():
    a = b = 1
    while True:
        yield a, b
        if a == b:
            a += 1
            b = 1
        else:
            b += 1

def test(a, b):
    return root((a ** power) + (b ** power)) % 1 == 0

power = int(input('Power: '))

generator = two_numbers()
for a, b in generator:
    result = test(a, b)
    print(a, b, result)
    if result:
        break
```

When run using powers of 12 (entering `12` at the prompt), it stops at:

```
17 1 True
```

This is probably due to the inaccuracy of the fractional indices.

How do I know if it has been rounded, or solve this problem otherwise?

Comment: mus be use float

Comment: `Fraction` doesn't work like that: check `Fraction(1 / 12)` vs `Fraction(1, 12)`. And using a `Fraction` in an exponent is useless, it gets converted to float anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, your problems come from precision. You can check this with :

```
print(np.finfo(float).eps)
# 2.22044604925e-16
```

or

```
print(np.finfo(np.float32).eps)
# 1.19209e-07
```

For more precision, you can use "Decimal" librairie and update your root function:

```
from decimal import Decimal

def root(num, power):
    return Decimal(num ** Decimal(1 / power))
```

Comment: `sys.float_info` provides a way of getting information about Python's `float` without recourse to a 3rd party package. (The OP isn't using NumPy.)

Comment: I have tested this solution, and I have ran it over 1600^12+1600^12, with no false positives observed.

Comment: This gives no guarantee that the algorithm is correct. Because of rounding errors, the values of `c` may be wrong and fail to match an existing solution. By the way, as written the function `root` always returns `1` ! And even after fixing, for `n = 2` no solutions are found. Hum...

Answer (score 3):

`Fraction` can't represent irrational numbers, so you'll run into rounding errors even if you use it. Avoiding floating point numbers completely leaves no room for rounding errors:

```
def is_perfect_kth_power(n, k):
    low = 1
    high = 1

    # Find an upper bound for the binary search
    while high**k < n:
        high *= 2

    while low + 1 < high:
        midpoint = (low + high) // 2

        if n < midpoint**k:
            high = midpoint
        elif midpoint**k < n:
            low = midpoint
        else:
            return True

    return False
```

Since you're trying to find things that don't exist, I don't think runtime is an issue here.

Comment: Looking for the closest integer power is indeed a good cure. Dichotomic search is probably overkill here as the sums `a^n+b^n` will be tried in increasing order, and `c` can progress concurrently.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the first order term of the relative error to 17 for

```
(17**12+1)**(1.0/12)
```

is

```
1.0/(p*a^p) = 1.0/(12*17**12) = 1.43031501388558e-16.
```

This is smaller than the machine epsilon `2.2e-16`, i.e., not large enough to influence the mantissa of a 64bit float which is used in the fractional power computation.

---

You can use

```
def test(a, b):
    num=a**power+b**power; 
    c=root(num); 
    return num - int(c+0.5)**power == 0
```

until that fails due to overflow problems in the conversion from float to integer.

---

You can reverse that computation of the first order relative error. You get from the equation that `c` is larger than `a` and thus as integer you need `c` at least `a+1`. Inserting gives

```
 a**p+b**p >= (a+1)**p = a**p + p*a**(p-1) + ...
```

by the binomial theorem, so that you want at least

```
b**p > p*a**(p-1)  <==>  b > a*(p/a)**(1/p)
```

Using this lower bound should avoid these rounding problems.

For `a=17` this gives `17` as lower bound for `b`, thus no case to try under the rule `b<a`. For `a=171` the lower bound is `138` and indeed the first case with `c>=172` is for `b=138`.

Answer (score 1):

I would use the following strategy to keep working with integers:

- for all values of `a` in the desired range, compute `a^n`,
- scan all values of `b` in the desired range and compute `a^n + b^n`; at the same time, maintain a variable `c` and ensure that at all times `(c-1)^n < a^n + b^n <= c^n`.

As `a^n + b^n` will go increasing, only the right-hand inequality can get invalidated and you will fix by incrementing `c` as many times as necessary. To initialize `c`, it suffices to notice that `a^n < a^n + 1` and start with `c= a`.

```
n= 2
m= 50
for a in range(1, m+1):
    an= a ** n
    c= a; cn= an
    for b in range(a+1, m+1):
        anbn= an + b ** n
        while anbn > cn:
            c+= 1
            cn= c ** n
        if anbn == cn: # Bingo!
            print a, b, c
```

For the case `n=2`,

```
3 4 5
5 12 13
6 8 10
7 24 25
8 15 17
9 12 15
9 40 41
10 24 26
12 16 20
12 35 37
14 48 50
15 20 25
15 36 39
16 30 34
18 24 30
20 21 29
20 48 52
21 28 35
24 32 40
24 45 51
27 36 45
28 45 53
30 40 50
33 44 55
36 48 60
40 42 58
...
```

(Note that we start from `b= a+1` to avoid duplicates.)